# How to change 2D sprite object by clicking? and it will change back when clicking another object, like focus effect in web design

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wish to find out how to change a object (sprite) by clicking (then it will change to another sprite object).

If I click another object, the previous changed object will then changed back, and the newly clicked object will be changed to another object.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please note anything other than a question is irrelevant information. Putting "urgent" in the question is not only unnecessary, it will also make people avoid your question. Please also specify what you have tried to solve your problem, and what the problems are you are running into.

Comment: ok, I am sorry, I will avoid it next time.

Comment: This could help: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72765/change-the-sprite-of-a-object-in-unity

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) try to give a detailed information about your question. What issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question.

Comment: thanks Andrea, it really helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to Change Sprite**

```
private void changeSprite(Sprite newSprite){
  this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = newSprite;  
}
//if the object is an image you should use this instead
private void changeSprite(Sprite newSprite){
  this.GetComponent<Image>().overrideSprite = newSprite;  
}
```

**How to get it by "Clicking"**

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
  changeSprite();
}
//If it's a UI Element
public Button btn;
private void Start()
{
  btn.onClick.AddListener(changeSprite);  
}
```

**The "swap stuff" effect, note that this is "static" for only 2 objects, you need to iterate over a list/array or whatever to works dynamically independant over the number of objects.**

```
//Your Object Class
public Sprite initialSprite;
public Sprite changeSprite;
public bool isChanged = false;
public GameObject  otherObject;

private void OnMouseDown()
{
  changeSprite(changeSprite);
  isChanged = !isChanged;
  if(otherObject.isChanged)
  {
    otherObject.changeSprite(initialSprite); 
    otherObject.isChanged = !otherObject.isChanged; 
  }
}
```